# In mobile view Questions tab, any selection will redirect to show:newest

Tags: bug, mobile-web

In the mobile view on the *Questions* tab, if I select any option in the *show* it will redirect to *newest* option only.

For an example, if I select featured oprion, it will redirect to newest only.

> [image: wide demo pic]

---

**System information:**
Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.91
Android version 6.0.1

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in Safari. Please add some system info. :)

Comment: @Catija System information added